# Смена информации в главном окне программы PyQt5 (Qt designer)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Например, есть главное окно программы с 2 кнопками, "кошки" и "собаки", по нажатии одной из них хочу, чтобы информация в этом окне поменялась на другую, где соответственно я пропишу новые кнопки с перечислением этих "кошек" и "собак".

Я должен это реализовать путем создания двух дополнительных окон и указания связи между главным окном и одним из вспомогательных посредством кнопки? Или в Qt дизайнере есть какая-нибудь функция со слоями на одном главном окне, которые также можно связать посредством кнопок?

Comment: Вадим Лорейнченко, пожалуйста, покажите что вы уже написали и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick я пока что подготовил только формы нужных окон в qt дизайнере, а вот как их связать так и не понял

Comment: Вадим Лорейнченко, опубликуйте формы, которые надо связать.